# Retrieve image from database with PHP and use in Flutter project (in Dart)

Tags: php, json, flutter, dart

I have a database with an image column (blob) and several text columns.
My task-
PHP - I want to retrieve the image and text columns and encode it with JSON
Flutter/Dart - Receive the data and display in a list

I have no idea how to, so help please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

make sure to create your php code and make sure its working.
if you can retrieve your data correctly, if your image is a Path use Image.File, or you can use Image.network(*your_ip_address* + *your_path*.toString()) or Image.network("*your_ip_address*${*your_path*}")